# How can I modify a label with a secondary thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have an ASP.NET page that makes web service calls and gets a response back with data with the point being to basically make a test call to monitor if the service is up or down. Since there are many calls being made, I have decided to run them all on their own thread and update the UI on the web page with the response value once they finish and return.

I have done this before in Windows Form applications with the this.Invoke methodology to have the main thread then update the label text but through my searching, I have not found a similar way to do this in ASP. I see the services return a response and the code to update the label text runs through on each secondary thread, but none of the labels text changes.

Is there any other way that I can change label text created on the main thread with a secondary thread similar to how the Invoke would have done?

Comment: (A previous commenter pointed out that the original request will be long complete and the thread reallocated elsewhere). You could have a look at SignalR - your background thread should be able to raise a notification via the hub which could notify the clients. It may require some significant design changes / retrofitting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to perform an AJAX call.  If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, you'll need to enable partial page updates by using an `UpdatePanel` and a `ScriptManager` control.

[Take a look at Microsoft's introduction to the UpdatePanel control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

If you're using MVC or SignalR there are other ways to do this, but I'm assuming that as a WinForms developer that you're likely using WebForms.

Comment: I have an update panel already in place with the ScriptManager. I have tried calling the updatePanel.Update() method at the end of the method the threads are calling. Still seeing no changes on the UI.

Comment: @RJ130 Would you be able to edit in some source code to your original question? Seeing what you're doing would be helpful in understanding why it isn't working.